# What is Carathéodory Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convex-analysis

I recently read the Carathéodory theorem in special theorems on derivatives. I was wondering what exactly is the use of this? What does it show?

My guess is- it tells that if $f$ is a differentiable function at $c$ then there will be another function $\phi$ defined in the same way such that the value of $\phi$ at $c$ will be same as $f^{\prime}$ at $c$ and vice versa.

Comment: IMO it is just useful in proving the chain rule and that's it.

Comment: Honestly, that was the only place where I saw its application! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to point this out here for future reference:

Caratheodory theorem is extremely useful if you want to define continuously differentiable functions $f$ on an interval $I$. If $\phi(x)$ is a continuous function then, $f$ is continuously differentiable.